# Ошибка "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'"

Tags: python

написал вот такой код:

```
a = int(input ("::: "))

if a > "80":
    print("too much")

elif a < "5":
    print ("too little")
    
else:
    print("started")
```

но он выдает ошибку `"TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'"`  из ошибки понятно что не существует метода > для int но как это исправить я не знаю

Comment: А вы сравнивайте числа с числами или строки со строками и всё будет нормально. Вы сами превратили `a` в число функцией `int`, а теперь сравниваете его со строками.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Убери кавычки из чисел, вот и все:

```
a = int(input ("::: "))

if a > 80:
    print("too much")

elif a < 5:
    print ("too little")
    
else:
    print("started")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = int(input("::: "))

if a > 80:
    print("too much")

elif a < 5:
    print ("too little")
    
else:
    print("started")
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]